# Failed to start debugger in Eclipse (Win10)

Tags: windows, eclipse, debugging, msys2

I am trying to debug a Fortran Console application from Eclipse under Windows 10.

Building and running work fine, using the compiler from MSYS2.
However, starting the debugger yields:

Error in final launch sequence:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process /c/Windows/system32/E:/till/uni/wasa/wasa_git/WASA-SED/E:/till/uni/wasa/wasa_git/WASA-SED/wasa_dbg.exe, (error 2).
```

The gdb.exe is found correctly, but it seems as if the path to the binary is prepended with `/c/Windows/system32/` and one time too many the actual path `E:/till/uni/wasa/wasa_git/WASA-SED`, which obviously causes gdb to fail.

I tried using absolute, relative, and no paths to the binary in the debug configuration settings, all with the same result.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem seems to be related to the version of gdb that I use.
I had used an instance from a recent MSYS2 distribution (i.e. GNU gdb (GDB) 11.1), which produced the error above.

Falling back on an older version (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1) worked as expected.
I solved this by prepending the PATH-variable with the path to the old MSYS2 directory:

`SET PATH=c:\mingw4eclipse\bin\;c:\mingw4eclipse\mingw_64\bin\;%PATH%`

Putting this into batch file that then calls Eclipse ensures that no other workflows (using the newer MSYS2) are affected.